# check a url is from a specific site

Tags: c#

i want to check if a url is from youtube.com website or the mobile version of the site.

is there a robust way to do this?

checking the url contains "youtube.com" does not seem good to me.
whats the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class to parse the URL and compare to the `Host` property.

```
Uri uri = new Uri(myURL);
return uri.Host.Equals("youtube.com", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a foolproof way to make sure it's youtube.com coming in, but checking REFERER is really not all that solid: the page linking to you can fake its referer header any time it wants to:

http://www.stardrifter.org/refcontrol/

It'll be interesting to see how the security gurus answer this question.

-- pete